# why wont Xcode save my files?

Tags: xcode, file, permissions, permission-denied, read-write

I have been working on an app in XCode for a while now and added a new file to the app today.  When I went to save it, XCode came up with an alert saying that I did not have permission to save the file and to check in the info part of the file.  I did, but the file says that it is read & write so there should be no reason why this happened.  I then tried deleting it and creating it again but it again said the same thing.  I then deleted it and started working on the mainViewController file and the same thing came up again!  I did not do anything to the computer or the files yesterday except for I added some code in them that seemed to have worked just fine.  What can I do to fix this?

P.S.: This happens with all new files I create - not just the .m, .h, & .xib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions on the directory where you're trying to save the file. Also, check the permissions on the files in the project bundle.

Comment: how would I check the permissions in the directory?

Comment: Select the folder and type command-I (Get Info). Alternately, `ls -ld <somePath>` from a command line. You can't create a file in a given directory without write permission on that directory.